# Issue on Nvidia Jetson Nano and Raspberry Pi V2.1 Camera ( Camera Does Not Open)

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using Nvidia Jetson Nano and Raspberry Pi V2.1 Camera for color detection via Python and OpenCV. However, the codes that worked on my computer do not work on Jetson Nano and I keep getting errors. The camera is working, I checked it. Also, Jetson Nano is in operation but camera does not opened. I could not get the problem.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
dispW=320
dispH=240
flip=2
camSet='nvarguscamerasrc !  video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3264, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=21/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method='+str(flip)+' ! video/x-raw, width='+str(dispW)+', height='+str(dispH)+', format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(camSet)
lower_red = (147,46,91)
upper_red = (180,255,255)

while True:
    ret, frame=cam.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red,upper_red)
    final_frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask = mask)
    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Final", final_frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==ord("q"):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is the error:

```
3.2.0
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn== 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-XDqSFW/opencv 3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9815 Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "red.py", line 15, in <module>
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.error: /build/opencv-XDqSFW/opencv 3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9815: error: (-215) (scn== 3 || scn== 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor
```

Comment: Did you enable picamera? Sudo raspi-config

Comment: I am using Jetson Nano, not Raspberry Pi.  When I write "sudo raspi-config" on Terminal, it says "command not found"

Comment: cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER) or Add this at the end video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 Or Opencv only uses the pipeline string (without single quotes).

Comment: I noticed you using BGR2HSV. how about to change this format=(string)I420?

Comment: I changed to cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER), bu it gave the same error.  I added the "drop=1" at the end, but the result is also the same error.

Comment: You mean instead of "format=BGR ! appsink", I should write "format=(string)I420" ?

Comment: Yes I used raspberry pi. What is your Debian version? But on my side. I got everything working.

Comment: Without using Gstreamer. Does your picamera working using cv2.VideoCapture(0)?

Comment: Jetson Nano os is based on Ubuntu 18.04, not Debian.

Comment: If I use cv2.VideoCapture(0),it shows full of green screen instead of image from the camera.

Comment: Can you try this? gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc sensor_id=0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3280, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! 'video/x-raw, width=816, height=616' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e

Comment: This command opened the camera, yes. If I add this on camset line in my code, do you think it works?

Comment: Try it by yourself. Remove this or not ...gst-launch-1.0

Comment: It didn't work.  This error is showed.   camSet='nvarguscamerasrc sensor_id=0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3280, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! 'video/x-raw, width=816, height=616' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e'
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That is all I can troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that OpenCV is compiled with gstreamer backend support, using `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`, and than check `Media I/O:` section.
2. You need to make sure that you have [configured drivers](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/archives/l4t-archived/l4t-3261/index.html#page/Tegra%20Linux%20Driver%20Package%20Development%20Guide/hw_setup_jetson_io.html#wwpID0E02D0HA) using `sudo /opt/nvidia/jetson-io/jetson-io.py`, than you can see your cam using command `ls /dev/video*`. If not, may be you need to remove [R8 resistor](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/raspberry-pi-hq-camera-compatibility/123646/23?page=2) on camera board (valid for Raspberry Camera HQ (IMX477)).